# How do I create a new column and fill it with the content of another column with R's tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Current data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("Steve", "Darrel", "Barney", "Lola"),
  age = c("12_pink", "14_green", "19_blue", "24_cyan"),
  sex = c("M", "M", "M", "F")
)
```

I am trying to fill the 'colors' column with the color that is in the 'age' column so it looks like the following.

Desired data:

| name | age | sex | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | 12 | M | pink |
| Darrel | 14 | M | green |
| Barney | 19 | M | blue |
| Lola | 24 | F | cyan |

Anyways to do so? I was thinking of using `mutate()` to create the `color` column but wasn't sure how to fill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyr::separate` can help here:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("Steve", "Darrel", "Barney", "Lola"),
  age = c("12_pink", "14_green", "19_blue", "24_cyan"),
  sex = c("M", "M", "M", "F")
)

df |> separate(age, into = c("color", "age"))

#>     name color   age sex
#> 1  Steve    12  pink   M
#> 2 Darrel    14 green   M
#> 3 Barney    19  blue   M
#> 4   Lola    24  cyan   F
```

Comment: You are such a life saver!!!!!

Comment: @morningstarsaus Something that I find helps me is that when I know what I want my data to *look* like, but not how to do it, I look at the tidyr cheat sheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/tidyr.pdf

Comment: thank you for the tip! if i wanted to manipulate a data column "Age" that has the element "Age13" in it, how could I change it to be just "13"? Not sure how to remove "Age" in an element of the data. Thanks again.

Comment: @morningstarsaus For that you'd probably have to do some regex magic. Since there's no 'separation character' (that is, you want to keep everything, where as in the case of `12_pink` you removed the `_`) I would probably do two separate `mutate`s to make a columns for `color` and `age`, and use `str_extract` or `grep` to pull the values out from the original `age` column. btw if the answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? It helps me out.

Comment: Sure how do I do that?

Comment: There should be a checkmark right next to the up and down voting arrows!